# ASP.NET Dynamic HTML Table Update

Tags: asp.net, html, dynamic

My question is how do I embed ASP.NET code in my HTML document. I'm very new to this stuff and not sure how to incorporate my ASP.NET code to be executed into my webpage. I have already crafted the code to be used in my site, however, I have no clue how to add this code so that it will be executed in my webpage.

I basically just want to update a HTML table when a form is filled out and the submit button is pressed. I also want to be able to add multiple rows to the table without overwriting the original ones. I've figured out how to update my table dynamically, but just don't know how to incorporate it in my webpage.

For example, PHP (at the tope of the page):

```
<?php 
   //PHP code....
?>
```

What about ASP.NET code?

Any direction/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The <%  %> tags can be used to include ASP code in any part of an HTML document.

```
<html>
<body>
<%
response.write("My first ASP script!")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/default.asp